# Necessary conditions for convergence of a product?

Tags: definition, infinite-product

In the text "Function Theory of a Complex Variable" the definition and conditions for convergence for an Infinite product is given in $(1.)$ i'm initially having trouble discerning whether both conditions have to be met for the convergence of a product.

$(1.)$

An infinite product:
$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1+a_{j})$$

is said to converge if

$(1.)$ only a finite number $a_{j_{i}}, \cdot \cdot \cdot, a_{j_{k}}$ of those $a_{j}$'s are equal to $-1$

$(2.)$ if $N_{o} > 0$ is so large that $a_{j} \neq -1$ for $j > N_{o}$, then:

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{j = N_{o} +1 }(1+a_{j})$$

Comment: I think it’s clear what it means for a product to converge in the good situation that it has no zero factors. Certainly a product may diverge and satisfy only (1.), so it looks to me as if both (1.) and (2.) must be satisfied. I guess they’re designing the definition so that a product will converge if and only if its every tail converges.

Comment: Hmm now looking at it seems the convergence criteria  is true, how would show condition $(1.)$ my thought would be to expand the product and multiply a finite amount of terms till it equals $-1$.

Comment: No no. You see whether (1.) is satisfied simply by looking at the separate factors. If none is zero, then (1.) is satisfied; similarly if only one of them is zero; etc. (Maybe I should remark in addition that I think this definition is unnecessarily complicated.)

Comment: Ahh ok now I understand